# How to search all the amazon connect customer profiles using API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

I am struggling with searching all the amazon connect customer profiles at once by using rest API.

I already know the API that retrieve one or more than two customer profiles via specific key name such as profile ID or account ID etc.

However not list all customer profiles.

Here's my JavaScript code for searching one profile.

```
session.profileClient.searchProfiles({
            "DomainName": "", // required
            "KeyName": searchKey, // required
            "Values": [searchValue] // required
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log('Success response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
        }).catch((errorResp) => {
            console.log('Error response: ' + JSON.stringify(errorResp));
        });
```

In this code, I have to put three parameters (`domainName`, `keyName`, `value`) and get one or two more results but all the results.

Any help in the right direction on how to list all Amazon Connect Customer Profile would be greatly appreciated.

I hope to get all the amazon connect customer profile list.

Comment: If the function isn't listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/customer-profiles/index.html) then it doesn't exist - and from what I've read, you can't get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `searchProfiles` you can use `listProfiles`.
Here's relevent code:

```
session.profileClient.listProfiles({
  "DomainName": "", // required
  "MaxResults": 100 // The maximum number of profiles to return per request (adjust this as needed)
}).then((res) => {
  console.log('Success response: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
}).catch((errorResp) => {
  console.log('Error response: ' + JSON.stringify(errorResp));
});
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: session.profileClient.listProfiles is not a function"
I got this error message in my chrome console.
I think the listProfiles doesn't exist in the amazon-connect-customer-profiles.js file.
Are there any other solutions?